# Resolve/register generic object by string value in Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have an interface `IImportCommand<T>`

```
public interface IImportCommand<T> where T : ImportModelBase
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

implemented object `ImportEntityCommand<T>`

```
public class ImportEntityCommand<T> : ICommand, IImportCommand<T> where T : ImportModelBase
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and some models from `ImportModelBase`

```
UserImportModel : ImportModelBase
PersonImportModel : ImportModelBase
```

and for `ImportEntityCommand`

```
ImportUserCommand : ImportEntityCommand<UserImportModel>
ImportPersonCommand: ImportEntityCommand<PersonImportModel>
```

etc

To build ImportEntityCommand I want to do something like this when string parameter is "user"

```
new ImportUserCommand()
{
    Date = body.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Items = body.Data.Select(d => d.ToObject<UserImportModel>()).ToList()
}
```

and when "person" then

```
new ImportPersonCommand()
{
    Date = body.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Items = body.Data.Select(d => d.ToObject<PersonImportModel>()).ToList()
}
```

`body` is json from request.

Is it possible to register my interface and entities based on input strings to create desired command object?

---

The simplest solution would be to do it with a switch statement, but I would like something more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands should not be registered with Dependency Injection, but you could register a `Factory` that creates the commands based on input strings.

One way to do this without using switch statements would be to add the factory methods to an internal `Dictionary` where the key is the input string.

Maybe something like this could get you started;

**Factory** (registered with DI)

```
public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand Create(string type, DateTime dateTime, string json);
}

public class CommandFactory : ICommandFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, string, ICommand>> _dictionary = new ()
    {
        { "user", (dateTime, json) => new ImportUserCommand(dateTime, json) },
        { "person", (dateTime, json) => new ImportPersonCommand(dateTime, json) }
    };

    public ICommand Create(string type, DateTime dateTime, string json) => _dictionary[type](dateTime, json);
}
```

**Commands and models** (not registered)

```
public interface ICommand
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Command<T> : ICommand
{
    protected Command(DateTime dateTime, string json) { /* Set data from json */ }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ImportUserCommand : Command<UserImportModel>
{
    public ImportUserCommand(DateTime dateTime, string json) : base(dateTime, json) { }
}

public class ImportPersonCommand : Command<PersonImportModel>
{
    public ImportPersonCommand(DateTime dateTime, string json) : base(dateTime, json) { }
}

public class UserImportModel { }
public class PersonImportModel { }
```

Comment: well, you are right... it's a more efficient way to solve my "issue". thx.